# How to join two tables with multiple common fields for search filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 table bpi_registration and bpi_teamProfile. The fields in bpi_registration are :  `id, id_school, first_name,last_name,email,city,state,country` and fields in bpi_teamProfile table are `id_team, team_name, id_student1, id_student2, id_student3` now id_student1, id_student2, id_student3 contains the same `id` of students that were in bpi_registration. I am not sure how to connect multiple fields. The query that i have written is below. Please correct me if i am wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM bpi_registration
            INNER JOIN bpi_teamProfile
            ON bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student1
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student2
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student3
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student4
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student5
```

I am trying to implement search filter in such a way that when someone clicks on Team dropdown then the `firstname,lastname,email,city,state,country` from `bpi_registration`shows up. Below is my PHP code

```html
if (isset($_GET['Team']))
{

      
      
    $sql="SELECT * FROM bpi_registration
            INNER JOIN bpi_teamProfile
            ON bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student1
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student2
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student3
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student4
            AND bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student5"
            
    $userQuery = "{$sql} WHERE bpi_teamProfile.team_name = :team_id";
    $user = $db->prepare($userQuery);
    $user->execute(['team_id' => $_GET['Team']]);
    $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 

    if(isset($selectedUser))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['first_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['last_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_city'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_state'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

The URL looks when we click on team filter looks like this - https://www.example.com/retrieve1.php?Grade=&School=&Team=mary+winners&Students=

However i am not able to get the desired result.

Comment: @PiyushGupta no i am not

Comment: I think your query is correct, we don't know your actual requirement so can you update your question?.....and have you sufficient database for testing purpose?

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have updated my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unlikely the student id columns in a given row *all* map back to the same id (in registration)...or the query would be returning properly. If they are different, do want to 'OR' the join?

```
SELECT * FROM bpi_registration
            INNER JOIN bpi_teamProfile
            ON (bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student1)
            OR (bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student2)
            OR (bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student3)
            OR (bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student4)
            OR (bpi_registration.id=bpi_teamProfile.id_student5)
```